# Populate TableView with Data

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm making an app similar to Yelp. In a View controller, I have 2 views: UITableView with an outlet called 'list' and a mapView. At the top I have a Search Bar.

Populating a table view is usually simple, but I'm not using a UITableViewController, so its a little confusing.

At the very top, I added a global variable

```
var cell: UITableViewCell?
```

Then in a table function, I have

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("attractionCell") as! AttractionCell!

    if cell == nil {
    cell = AttractionCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "attractionCell")
    }
    cell.attractionName.text = title
    return cell

}
```

At the bottom, I have a function for when the Search Bar is clicked, and then it fetches data from Parse and I assign the name of the object to a variable called 'title'.

```
  func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
  var Query = PFQuery(className:"Stores")
  Query.whereKey("Location", nearGeoPoint:area, withinMiles: 5)
  Query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

   if error == nil {

    let objects = objects as! [PFObject]
    for object in objects {                    
   let title = object["name"] as! String
 self.cell?.attractionName.text = title
```

Why is my table view not populating?

Also, in the storyboard, the prototype cell in the tableView are of class AttractionCell and have a reuseIdentifier called attractionCell

Comment: Does it have something to do with the tableview row count?

Comment: Did you link the tableView to the delegate and dataSource ? Does your controller conform to (`UITableViewDelegate` and) `UITableViewDataSource` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this line should not work remove it :

```
    if cell == nil 
    {
cell = AttractionCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "attractionCell")
    }
```

**And also Remove the global var cell**

Then you should declare an array of string globally

```
var arrayData = [String]()
```

in your function remove that line :

```
 self.cell?.attractionName.text = title
```

and add this

```
  arrayData.append(title)  
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

In **numberofRowInSection()**

```
 return arrayData.count
```

In the **cellForRowAtIndexPath()**

```
 cell.attractionName.text = arrayData[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention in the Search Function, I assign the cell text to title. So if I don't have cell as a global variable, the search function won't recognize it

Comment: do us favor post all your code and the error you are having

Comment: Added everything at the top

Comment: check the edit code, you still need to remove what i told you to remove, follow the instruction then it should work

Comment: Yes! Now I'm trying to figure out how to add images to the cells. Do I add them to the same array? Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

Try not to writing the "?" on the first variable...

Like that:

```
var cell: UITableViewCell
```

Comment: When I do that, it says ViewController has no initializers

Comment: When you invoke that variable, you have to invoke it with ! in order to make it work